# How do I print a fingerprint (sha256 bytes) using colon notation?

Tags: python, hash, x509

I have an x509 certificate fingerprint which is basically just a SHA 256 byte string.

These are usually notated in the form `43:51:43:a1:b5:fc:8b:b7:0a:3a:a9:b1:0f:66:73:a8`.

Is there a more appropriate way to generate these from a byte string like `b'CQC\xa1\xb5\xfc\x8b\xb7\n:\xa9\xb1\x0ffs\xa8'`?

`binascii.hexlify(b'CQC\xa1\xb5\xfc\x8b\xb7\n:\xa9\xb1\x0ffs\xa8')` gets me halfway there (`b'435143a1b5fc8bb70a3aa9b10f6673a8'`), but I don't have any of the colons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
hashbytes = b'CQC\xa1\xb5\xfc\x8b\xb7\n:\xa9\xb1\x0ffs\xa8'
print(":".join([format(i,'02x') for i in hashbytes]))
```

`43:51:43:a1:b5:fc:8b:b7:0a:3a:a9:b1:0f:66:73:a8`

There's probably a shorter way, perhaps with the `format()` method on the `hexdigest()` string output.

Answer (score 3):

```py
no_colon = b'CQC\xa1\xb5\xfc\x8b\xb7\n:\xa9\xb1\x0ffs\xa8'.hex()
colon = ':'.join(no_colon[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(no_colon), 2))
```

Bascially, I used `.hex()` to essentially "remove" the `b''` in the string and convert it to hex.

Then, `':'.join(no_colon[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(no_colon), 2))` adds a colon after every 2 letters. I assume that's what you want. However, this will only work if there are always 2 characters between each colon.

This all outputs:

```py
43:51:43:a1:b5:fc:8b:b7:0a:3a:a9:b1:0f:66:73:a8
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the builtin hex function https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=hex#bytes.hex

You can add a parameter for a seperator.

```py
    hashbytes = b'CQC\xa1\xb5\xfc\x8b\xb7\n:\xa9\xb1\x0ffs\xa8'
    print(hashbytes.hex(":"))
```

```
    43:51:43:a1:b5:fc:8b:b7:0a:3a:a9:b1:0f:66:73:a8
```